# I'm trying to notify the observer when the request finished to stop showing the loading spinner

Tags: angular, httprequest, interceptor

I'm intercepting the requests through interceptor injecting the loadIndicatorService i created, its working fine, but as I'm loading users inside ngOnInit, the LoadIndicator consider the request as on the fly, the code is below:

```
    @Injectable()
export class AppHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor( private loadingIndicatorService: LoadingIndicatorService) { }
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    this.loadingIndicatorService.onStarted(request);

    const currentUser = localStorage.getItem('token');

      request = request.clone({
        url: `${environment.apiURL}/${environment.apiVersion}/${request.url}`,
        setHeaders: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          Authorization: `Bearer ${currentUser}`
        }
      });

    return next.handle(request).finally(() => this.loadingIndicatorService.onFinished(request));

  }
}
```

and the service:

```
    @Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
  })
export class LoadingIndicatorService {

  onLoadingChanged: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  /**
   * Stores all currently active requests
   */
  private requests: HttpRequest<any>[] = [];

  /**
   * Adds request to the storage and notifies observers
   */
  onStarted(req: HttpRequest<any>): void {
    this.requests.push(req);
    this.notify();
  }

  /**
   * Removes request from the storage and notifies observers
   */
  onFinished(req: HttpRequest<any>): void {
    const index = this.requests.indexOf(req);
    if (index !== -1) {
      this.requests.splice(index, 1);
    }
    this.notify();
  }

  /**
   * Notifies observers about whether there are any requests on fly
   */
  private notify(): void {
    this.onLoadingChanged.emit(this.requests.length !== 0);
  }
}
```

Comment: I can't understand what the question or problem is. What does "the LoadIndicator consider the request as on the fly" mean? What do you expect to happen and what happens instead? Note that you're still using the old RxJS 5 operators, and that EventEmitter sgould only ever be used for component outputs. You should use an RxJS Subject instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommand to create a service that broadcast the status of loading and this service is observed by the loading spinner component. Each action/request will update the status of the loading using this service.

An example:

```js
@Injectable()
export class LoaderService {
  private loaderSubject = new Subject<boolean>();

  constructor() {}

  show() {
    this.loaderSubject.next(true);
  }

  hide() {
    this.loaderSubject.next(false);
  }

  select(): Observable<boolean>{
    return this.loaderSubject.asObservable();
  }
}
```

The spinner component:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-loader',
  template: 'YOUR SPINNER'
})
/**
 * Loader Component to show a spinner when the state's show equals to true
 *
 */
export class LoaderComponent implements OnDestroy, OnInit {
  show = false;
  private subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private loaderService: LoaderService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.loaderService.select().subscribe(
      (state: boolean) => {
        this.show = state;
      }
    );
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.subscription) {
      this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
  }
}
```

Your interceptor:

```js
@Injectable()
export class AppHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor { 

constructor( private loader: LoaderService) { } 

intercept(request: HttpRequest, next: HttpHandler): Observable> {
  this.loadingIndicatorService.show();

  const currentUser = localStorage.getItem('token');

  request = request.clone({
    url: `${environment.apiURL}/${environment.apiVersion}/${request.url}`,
    setHeaders: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: `Bearer ${currentUser}`
    }
  });

  return next.handle(request).finally(() => this.loading.hide());
  } 
}
```